# Sets two labels from two different containers at same Y,c#

Tags: c#, forms, label

I have two labels, one that stored at TableLayoutPanel and other that on the form, I need to set the both at the same Y point, so I will see that they in the same "row"..

I add a picture so it will be easy to understand

[image]

I need that lablel11, label10 will be in the same Y point as "0","279"

Answer (score 0):

you can get the *real location on the form* of `Label11` and do this:

```
int Distance = 70;
Control control = label11;

Point locationOnForm = control.FindForm().PointToClient(control.Parent.PointToScreen(control.Location));

label10.Location = new Point(locationOnForm.X + Distance, locationOnForm.Y);
```

Comment: I need that label10 will be at the same Y as label279..I tried to do something with the proporites, set new location at the code and what you give..dosent work, the label dosent move at all

Comment: this code works correctly, But do you want to design a Control and set the Y in the property? @user2922456

Comment: Yes..and why you add to X cordinate 70?

Comment: it's just a distance between LabelA and LabelB